# string formatting in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, string-formatting

I want to ask quite simple question. I'm writing function converting raw image to bmp. Function name is `raw2bmp()` Now say I want to work with file `LENA.raw` so I type my function `raw2bmp('LENA.raw')`. My function produces output bmp image. I want it name `LENA.raw.bmp`. So the question is how to get file name as an array of symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found an answer. Maybe it will be useful for someone

function [ img1 ] = raw2bmp( in_file );

out_name = [in_file '.bmp'];

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sprintf()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) to format your string, like this:

```
file_to_save = sprintf('%s.bmp', input_file);
```

Then you can save the result to `file_to_save`.

Comment: I just posted easier way. Sorry to bother.

Comment: @MykolaServetnyk I prefer to use `sprintf()`, especially when I want my file name like `file_0005.bmp`, then I can simply use `sprintf('file_%04d.bmp', 5)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
function raw2bmp(name)
  fid=fopen(name);
  rawdata=fread(fid);
  %do the conversion of rawdata and save it to bmpdata
  newname=[name '.bmp'];
  imwrite(bmpdata,newname,'bmp');
end
```

Then you call the function

```
raw2bmp('LENA.raw')
```

which saves the bmp image under 'LENA.raw.bmp'